# Atmel Studio 7.0 and its installer throw error: "Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application."

Tags: installation, atmel, atmelstudio

When I try to run Atmel Studio 7.0, it throws an error,

> Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application

This error also appears multiple times when I install Atmel Studio. How can I fix it?

To fix this problem, I tried:

1. I tried both the offline installer and online installer.
2. I tried to install Atmel Studio in different directories. One of these directories is on disk C (system disk, SSD), and another one is on disk D (HDD).

I think that this error may happen because of the following things:

1. Once I messed with a disk C security property.
2. Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 is installed on my computer. I heard that Atmel Studio can conflict with it. The Atmel Studio installer also runs *Visual Studio isolating shell*.
3. I have antivirus software (not [Windows Defender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Defender)). Maybe it prevents the Atmel Studio installer from downloading something from the Internet.

My OS is [Windows 10 Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Baseline_editions) x64.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling VS isolated shell 2015? That's what ended up working for me.

Comment: "Have you tried reinstalling VS isolated shell 2015? That's what ended up working for me." – Luuk Wuijster. This answer helped me.

Comment: Thanks for the question, and +1. I had the same problem. @LuukWuijster Your comment was the solution for me, too. If you make that comment an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Binarus Okay great! I have made it an answer

Comment: Thanks again - upvoted as promised :-)

Answer (score 1):

This issue may be related to a conflict or an issue with the Visual Studio Isolated Shell 2015. This shell is a part of Atmel Studio's installation, and it can conflict with other instances or versions of Visual Studio installed on your system.

To resolve this issue, try reinstalling the Visual Studio Isolated Shell 2015.